# Retrieval of String with Regex undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to retrieve a string between to words using Regex, however, the result comes up with undefined and upon investigation, it seems I cannot look back with regex which makes me a little confused how to attempt the extraction.

```
Regex : (?<=1 x )(.*)(?= for)

String : 1 x String Name for x
```

To confirm I am trying to retrieve the string 'String Name' from the above string.

Edit: Possible that (?<=1 x ) is unsupported?

Comment: Yes. Javascript regex does not have lookbehinds

Comment: @slartidan I have tried i believe that will include the strings 'x' and 'for' i do not want this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript, see https://regexr.com/3p2r5 .

But you should not need them anyways - just use `x (.*) for` instead https://regexr.com/3p2qs . And then only use *group number one* of the result.

Full example code:

```js
const Regex = /x (.*) for/;
const String = "1 x String Name for x";

const match = Regex.exec(String);
document.write(match[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'group number one'?

Comment: So if i am correct group number one returns the entire 'x String Name for' but i need only 'String Name'